# Build a Timing system (RFID)

Tags: rfid

I volunteer in an association that raises funds to fight cancer. We do various activities. Since 3years we organize a Run&Bike but the number of participants increase every year and the timing system that we use begins to no longer suitable.

So, I am a software engineer and I would build a timing system with NFC chips or something like that.

After some search I saw this package https://www.atlasrfidstore.com/thingmagic-m6e-embedded-rfid-reader-module-developer-kit/.

That's enough or I forgot something ?

I also need some advices to realize this project.

Thank you in advance for your advice. Feel free to ask me any question that you judge useful.

Comment: Saw the price tag on your linked package and my jaw dropped at the price tag. Personally, I would find it most feasible and cost effective to use a raspberry PI and a [RFID module](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-nfc-rfid-on-raspberry-pi/overview). The main reason I would opt for a raspberry PI is the fact it can run Linux, and thus would be able to run or connect to a seperate MySQL or MaraiaDB database so you can use timestamps and ids to track your information.

Comment: raspberry and RFID module could be fine but I have not found a long distance RFID module for raspberry.

Comment: You could try the communicating R. PI devices over a network router. I've heard of routers like the ones from Ubiquiti reaching for miles if that's the type of range you need. If you have a computer hooked up via ethernet to the same router you could use that as a local DB for your timestamp data.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. My problem here is how can I create a timing system using RFID tags. Basically I would like to create a kind of RFID portal. Each participant would have on his bib a tag that would be detected when he crosses the finish line. This requires an RFID antenna that picks up several meters away

Comment: My mistake, I thought you were referring to the distance between the R. PI and a storage device. You'd need a specialized RIFD module for this. Most RFID modules I've seen (like on buildings) have very small effective radii.